# Position pseudo element behind parent

Tags: html, css, sass

I am attempting to place an image (after) behind a parent image. I've used boxes as example of what I am trying to achieve - the blue box is supposed to be behind the green box but no matter what z-index I use it doesn't seem to work.

```css
.box-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.box {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 52px;
  width: 72px;
  z-index: 53;
  top: 2%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  //position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  z-index: -3;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you add the pseudo element to the parent `.box-wrapper` instead, as follows: `.box-wrapper:before`, then position it `absolute`?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError because I have other objects in the .box-wrapper...

Comment: Ok then, why don't you include those elements in your code snippet?

Comment: The child elements inherits the `z-index` of their parents, `::after` pseudoelement is a virtual child of the selected element.

Comment: @iyuyguyg does any of these answers helped ? if yes mark as correct please. Also you should check http://stackoverflow.com/tour so you could better understand how stack works

Answer (score 3):

Remove the z-index of the `box` and add `position:absolute` for `box:after`

```
.box-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.box {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 52px;
  width: 72px;
  top: 2%;
}
.box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  z-index:-2;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2r3vw8j/)

Answer (score 0):

> The blue box is supposed to be behind the green box

---

Just remove all the irrelvant `z-index` values, then it works perfectly.

```css
.box-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.box {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 52px;
  width: 72px;
  top: 2%;
  color:white;

}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapper">
  <div class="box">I'm on top</div>
</div>
```